# Forcing figure placement in LaTeX, without affecting formatting in any way

Tags: latex

I'm trying to achieve a result where the text: "and repeat the following infinite number of times:" comes after the figure like [so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe0zO.png)

Currently the above mentioned part comes before the figure like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJI0E.png)

Here's how my code looks like at the moment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{The Koch Snowflake}

The \emph{Koch snowflake},
one of the first fractals, is based on work by the Swedish mathematician Helge von Koch~\cite{koch}. It is what we get if we start with an equilateral triangle
\begin{figure}[h] 
  \label{koch}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{snowflake.jpg}
  \caption{The Koch snowflake after zero, one, two, and three iterations.}
\end{figure}
and repeat the following an infinite number of times:
```

I've tried several methods but all of these modify the text formatting in some way.
Packages like "Float" seem to affect the width of the text above the figure, and `\\ and repeat...`  also affects the styling. My goal is to not in any way modify the formatting. I just want the figure to be in the correct place and the text below it to be correctly on the left side of the page (without affecting the text above the figure or the width of the figure itself)

Answer (score 0):

With the text from your example you can just start a new paragraph after the figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{The Koch Snowflake}

The \emph{Koch snowflake},
one of the first fractals, is based on work by the Swedish mathematician Helge von Koch~\cite{koch}. It is what we get if we start with an equilateral triangle
\begin{figure}[h] 
  \label{koch}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{The Koch snowflake after zero, one, two, and three iterations.}
\end{figure}

and repeat the following an infinite number of times:

\end{document}
```

[image]

(be aware that latex optimises the layout for the whole paragraph, depending on the exact text, changes further down the paragraph can effect text further up)